# Is there a way to find $x^n$ by using $(x-1)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Basically I was playing a game which the inventory items went up to 64 in the same stack and accidentally removed 15 (8+7) of those items(49) (i know it was kinda stupid how i found this fomula).
Long story short: I found this formula that helps me find the next or the last square giving one of the squares in consideration (works in **any** square):

**(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1**  - *square above*

**(x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1**  - *square below*

So i was thinking, is there any kind of formula that would work in **x^n** in the same way?

if not, would there be some kind of formula for that would work the same in **x^3**?

Comment: Just expand the binomial formula.  You will get the Pascal's Triangle, which tells you how to go from $x^n$ to $(x\pm 1)^n$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Both your formulas are special cases of the binomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: So, you're given $a=(x-1)^n$ and want $b=x^n$, without knowing $x$ but knowing $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying a polynomial by $x+1$ is the same as

1. increasing the degree of all terms (factor $x$),
2. adding back the polynomial (factor $1$).

Hence

$$(x+1)(x+1)=(x^2+x)+(x+1)=x^2+2x+1$$

$$(x+1)^2(x+1)=(x^3+2x^2+x)+(x^2+2x+1)=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$

$$(x+1)^3(x+1)=(x^4+3x^3+3x+x)+(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$$

and so on.

The coefficients of these polynomials are known as the *binomial coefficients*, and they can be arranged to form Pascal's triangle. From the previous considerations, you understand that a coefficient is the sum of the two coefficients above it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You know that

$(x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1$

So if you replace $x$ by $x-1$ and $x+1$ by $x$ you get

$x^2 = (x-1)^2 + 2(x-1) + 1$

The equivalent formulae for $x^3$ are

$(x+1)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 \\x^3 = (x-1)^3 + 3(x-1)^2 + 3(x-1) +1$

For other powers of $n$ see the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: "(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1"
ah that was what i was missing in my x^3 one!
thank you, i was almost literally breaking my head over this.